# Split or parse a string in java

Tags: java, arrays

I've a file sample.txt and its content will be

```
12345#ABCDEF#12345#ADCDE

12345#ABCDEF#12345#ADCDE

FHJI

KLMN

OPQ

12345#ABCDEF#12345#ADCDE
```

Now I want to split/parse the file based upon #

My output should be

```
Test1 : 12345

Test2 : ABCDEF

Test3 : 12345

Test4 : ADCDE

Test1 : 12345

Test2 : ABCDEF

Test3 : 12345

Test4 : ADCDE

        FHJI

        KLMN

        OPQ

Test1 : 12345

Test2 : ABCDEF

Test3 : 12345

Test4 : ADCDE
```

I wrote like below

```
String sCurrentLine;
String Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4 = "";

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\sample.txt"));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String line[] = sCurrentLine.split("#");
    Test1 = line[0];
    Test2 = line[1];
    Test3 = line[2]
    Test4 = line[3];
    System.out.println(Test1+"\n"+Test2+"\n"+Test3+"\n"+Test4);
    }
```

It is working if its only one line
or sample.txt haslike below

```
12345#ABCDEF#12345#ADCDE

12345#ABCDEF#12345#ADCDE
```

It is not working for top declared example.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please format your question properly. It'd help if the text file contents were formatted as code.

Comment: Hints: A) "is not working" is not sufficient. Where exactly are things failing?! Dont expect us to compile/run your code together with your data just to repro your problem B) **never** do a split and access array elements without proper length checking.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
String line[] = sCurrentLine.split("#");
```

Will split the string into `n` fragments, if there is no `#` present in the line you parse will crash. In order to fix the problem, you have 2 options:

- Fix the file
- Check array's lenght before assigning to avoid a [`AIOOBE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

  ```
  while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String line[] = sCurrentLine.split("#");

      Test1 = line[0];
      Test2 = line.lenght > 1 ? line[1] : "";
      Test2 = line.lenght > 2 ? line[2] : "";
      Test2 = line.lenght > 3 ? line[3] : "";

      System.out.println(Test1+"\n"+Test2+"\n"+Test3+"\n"+Test4);
   }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if it is possible to split your string in the amount of parts you want

```
String sCurrentLine;
String Test1 = "";
String Test2= "";
String Test3= "";
String Test4 = "";

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\sample.txt"));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String line[] = sCurrentLine.split("#");
    if (line.length >= 4) {
        Test1 = line[0];
        Test2 = line[1];
        Test3 = line[2]
        Test4 = line[3];
    } else {
         Test4 = line[0] + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(Test1+"\n"+Test2+"\n"+Test3+"\n"+Test4);
}
```

Comment: Can it will be possible to store Test4 = line[3] in if condition and line[0] in else in same string variable with "\n" seperation ?

Comment: Do you mean `Test4 = line[0] + "\n"`?

Comment: String sCurrentLine;
String Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4 = "";

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\sample.txt"));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String line[] = sCurrentLine.split("#");
    if (line.length >= 4) {
        Test1 = line[0];
        Test2 = line[1];
        Test3 = line[2]
        Test4 = line[3];
        
    } else {
         Test4 = line[0];
    }
System.out.println(Test1+"\n"+Test2+"\n"+Test3+"\n"+Test4);
}

If i print like below I need to get like below
Test1 : 12345
Test2 : ABCD
Test3 : 12345
Test4 : ADCD
FHJI
KLMN
OPQ

Comment: @Hello Change the code inside the else into `Test4 = line[0] + "\n";` and I think it will work.

Comment: If I print all test1,...,test4 after else I need to get all values

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, to check that you have enough segments in your string.

```
String sCurrentLine;
String Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4 = "";

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\sample.txt"));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

  String line[] = sCurrentLine.split("#");
  if(line.length >= 4){
    Test1 = line[0];
    Test2 = line[1];
    Test3 = line[2]
    Test4 = line[3];
  }
    System.out.println(Test1+"\n"+Test2+"\n"+Test3+"\n"+Test4);
}
```